how to make it so that the buttons are only displayed when loged_in = false
i want it to be so that if you are loged in , you arent displayed the login and register buttons.
I tried doing it like this, but its not working

  var loginBtn = document.getElementById("LoginBtn"); // Corrected here
  var registerBtn = document.getElementById("RegisterBtn"); // Corrected here

  if (loggedin == False) {
      loginBtn.style.display = "inline-block"; // Show
      registerBtn.style.display = "inline-block"; // Show
    } else {
      loginBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Hide
      registerBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Hide
    }

this is the app, it is set to always true for debuggings sake.
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if flask.session.get('username'):
        return flask.render_template('index.html', loggedin=True)
    else:
        return flask.render_template('index.html', loggedin=True)


You need to make some changes in your code, like the provided code. First, in the if condition you are checking (loggedin == False) but the more optimized way to do this is like (!loggedin). Next. you need to hide the button when the user logs in, so instead of hiding visibility, simply you need to display none so, that when a user doesn't log in, the login and register buttons will not have a place in HTML.
var loginBtn = document.getElementById("LoginBtn"); // Corrected here
var registerBtn = document.getElementById("RegisterBtn"); // Corrected 
here

  if (!loggedin) {
      loginBtn.style.display = "inline-block"; // Show
      registerBtn.style.display = "inline-block"; // Show
    } else {
      loginBtn.style.display = 'none'; // none
      registerBtn.style.display = 'none'; // none
    }

